# PHP : What is the benefit of spl_autoload_register? Performance of includes

Tags: php, performance, oop, autoload

I've been reading about `spl_autoload_register` functions as a substitution of `require`, `require_once`, `include`, & `include_once`. Although there is much discussion about how to implement this, the documentation isn't too detailed and there isn't an explaination as to how it would be beneficial vs the original ways.

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

I am wondering how `spl_autoload_register` works?

Is there a performance difference when using `spl_autoload_register`?

How does it handle many require statements (more than 20) in cross linked classes? (Wouldn't this still result in duplicate requires?)

Comment: You should always `require_once` when loading class definitions, which removes the risk of duplication - which would cause a fatal error if it happened.

Comment: @DaveRandom I use `require_once` in all my classes, but the `require_once` statements and class instances are created at the top of the script page. What is the difference with `spl_autoload_register` ?

Comment: @DaveRandom: I disagree.  The `include_once` and `require_once` directives are not only less performant, but more importantly, they promote sloppy organization and architecture.

Comment: @drrcknlsn `they promote sloppy organization and architecture` - how so? I mean I accept that code should be designed in such a way that one would never end up even trying to load the class file more than once, but it's nice to know that the safeguard is there.

Comment: @DaveRandom: You've answered your own question. :-)  Safe-guards aren't really very good safe-guards if they allow bad things to happen and then sweep them under the rug so you never know about it.

Comment: @drrcknlsn what do you suggest? I'm looking for the most performance efficient way. I completely agree that require statements use up resources & most of the time I'm including `require_once` statements just too make sure I didn't miss any.

Comment: @mlishn: When you need a file, `require` it.  I personally always use PSR-0 autoloading for my projects, which eliminates 99.9% of the need to require anything manually, though.

Comment: @drrcknlsn can you post an example? I'm open to all options. I need to deviate away from including tons of `require_once` statements at the top of scripts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't ever tested (nor worried about) performance, but I *always* use an autoloader, because it makes your life sooo much easier.

For an implementation see: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

What happens is that when you try to access a class e.g. `Foo` of which the file isn't loaded yet. The autoloader will kick in and tries to load the file belonging to the class.

This can be easily done by "correctly" organizing the files in your project. Lets say you have a class `\Project\Http\Client` (or the "old style" non namespaced `Project_Http_Client`) it will try to load the file: `Project/Http/Client.php`.

Comment: how does that work if class instances are created at the top of the script ?

Comment: One of the first things you include is the autoloader in your script. Before you are creating instances of other classes. I always just initialize the autoloader in my bootstrap file.

Comment: Right but isn't that almost equivalent to just `require_once` at the top of the script? I'm trying to limit the number of duplicate `require_once` statements from class to class

Comment: No because you only need to register the autoloader once and it will require all the files for you. Otherwise you would have to use `require` for every class you are trying to load.

Comment: @mlishn: If you use proper PSR-0 autoloading and follow the conventions with your class file organization on the file system, then you'll almost _never_ need to manually require a class file.

Comment: so do I include all the classes in need in *one* autoload?

Comment: You don't include anything. You just include the autoloader and that's it. The autoloader will automagically load all the other files for you

Comment: So, can i create one autoloader and just include that on every page. Then it will choose which classes I need? Does this happen when the class instance is created?